# Reading/writing in Linux kernel space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, read-write

I want to add functions in the Linux kernel to write and read data. But I don't know how/where to store it so other programs can read/overwrite/delete it.

Program A calls `uf_obj_add(param, param, param)` it stores information in memory.
Program B does the same.
Program C calls `uf_obj_get(param)` the kernel checks if operation is allowed and if it is, it returns data.

Do I just need to `malloc()` memory or is it more difficult ?
And how `uf_obj_get()` can access memory where `uf_obj_add()` writes ?
Where to store memory location information so both functions can access the same data ?

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto-8.html) and [HERE](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html)

Comment: Can't you use some existing file system for that (perhaps a `tmpfs`, or add your new entries in `/proc/` ...)? I would believe you should not patch the kernel for such things

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'd like to try this way...

Comment: You certainly don't use `malloc` in kernel land (but some flavor of `kalloc`) because you don't use the C standard library in kernel code (which is conceptually freestanding)

Comment: I strongly recommend to be *very* familiar with [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) -in user land- before attempting to write kernel code; BTW, how would you use your newly added kernel functions (in some driver, then which one? in some new syscall?...)?

Comment: The only thing I did in the Linux source code was modifying the return value of a function (just to test something). So I don't know more. I found tutorials on how to add functions and now I want to learn more to modify it. There are other ways to achieve what I want to do but I want to try that.

Comment: http://kernelnewbies.org/ has probably relevant information; however, my first hint about kernel patching is: don't patch the kernel, try to find a user-land approach...

Comment: Why not patching ? Why ? It's an opportunity to learn.

Comment: Indeed, learning is a good motivation. But be prepared to break your system (so backup your important data on some external media).

Comment: OP is clearly a beginner programmer in general and as such doing any kind of kernel work is not advisable. As such I can only recommend sticking to userspace. Just in case this was supposed to be used in the real world, the mechanism in question looks like an attempt to provide functionality equivalent to already existing mechanisms anyway (e.g. sysvipc).

Comment: @employeeofthemonth What do you mean by "in general" ? I don't know a lot about kernel hacking but I started to code years ago. I have to create functions for a new security system and for several reasons I was told not to use existing functions. No read(), open() and stuff. And among other requirements the code mustn't be in user space. So please stop telling me to try writing UL code or using existing mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by commentators to your question, achieving this in userspace would probably be much safer. However, if you insist on achieving this by modifying kernel code, one way you can go is implementing a new device driver, which has functions such as read and write that you may implement according to your needs, in order to have your processes access some memory space. Your processes can then work, as you described, by reading from and writing onto the same space more or less as if they are reading from/writing to a regular file.

I would recommend reading quite a bit of materials before diving into kernel code, though. A good resource on device drivers is [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). Even though a significant portion of its information may not be up-to-date, you may find [here](https://github.com/duxing2007/ldd3-examples-3.x) a version of the source code used in the book ported to linux 3.x. You may find what you are looking for under the directory [scull](https://github.com/duxing2007/ldd3-examples-3.x/tree/master/scull).

Again, as pointed out by commentators to your question, I do not think you should jump right into updating the execution of the kernel space. However, for educational purposes `scull` may serve as a good starting point to read kernel code and see how to achieve results similar to what you described.